# node.js wait function end

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am a newcomer to node.js.
I have a question, how do I continue after other .js waits for the call function to end the return value?

The following is an example:

```
function test() {

    var queryString = "select * from Product where PEnable = 'true' and PType = '1'"
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    var conn = pool;
    let jim = '';
    return conn.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);

       return req.query(queryString).then(function (result) {

           return result['recordset'][0]['Name'];

            conn.close();

            console.log('result >' , result['recordset'][0]['Name']);

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Unable to add result >', err);
            conn.close();
        });

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to SQL >', err);
    });
    return jim;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. you can simply use async await or .then() to wait for this function to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async/await.
**async**: to make the function to return a Promise.
**await**: to make JavaScript wait until that Promise settles and then returns its result

For example, your code could be rewritten like

```
async function test() {

    var queryString = "select * from activities"
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
    var conn = await pool

    const req =  conn.request();
    const result = await req.query(queryString)
    var returnValue = result['recordset'][0]['Name']
    pool.close()

    return returnValue

}
```

Then you can call it with await keyword

```
var yourvalue = await test()
```

Comment: can i know how to call from another .js
And waiting for this function done & return value?
thanks.

Comment: you can try  var yourvalue = await test(). It will wait for test() done and get value